# Select parent and child from the same table

Tags: sql-server-2005, correlated-subquery

I have a emp table,

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Emp](
    [EmpId] [int] NULL,
    [EmpName] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [ManagerId] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Now, insert below values into the table

```
   Insert Into Emp Values(1,'A',0)
Insert Into Emp Values(2,'B',1)
Insert Into Emp Values(3,'C',2)
Insert Into Emp Values(4,'D',2)
Insert Into Emp Values(5,'E',4)
Insert Into Emp Values(6,'F',4)
Insert Into Emp Values(7,'G',4)
Insert Into Emp Values(8,'H',6)
Insert Into Emp Values(9,'I',5)
Insert Into Emp Values(10,'J',7)
Insert Into Emp Values(11,'K',4)
```

I want to list employee name and their manager name in select statement.

What I am doing now is creating a temporary table which has all manager name and their Id.

Then getting the name from the manager table based on Id.

But I know this is not a correct way, in fact it is complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a recursive CTE (Common Table Expression) for this:

```
-- define the recursive CTE and give it a name
;WITH Hierarchy AS
(
    -- "anchor" - top-level rows to select, here those with ManagerId = 0
    SELECT EmpId, EmpName, NULL AS 'MgrId', CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS 'MgrName', 1 AS 'Level'
    FROM dbo.Emp
    WHERE ManagerId = 0

    UNION ALL

    -- recursive part - join an employee to its manager via ManagerId -> mgr.EmpId
    SELECT e.EmpId, e.EmpName, mgr.EmpId, mgr.EmpName, mgr.Level + 1 AS 'Level'
    FROM dbo.Emp e
    INNER JOIN Hierarchy mgr ON e.ManagerId = mgr.EmpId
)
SELECT * FROM Hierarchy
```

Comment: Thanks for your query. Meanwhile I have written this, can you tel me where I am incorrect, please. I have just read about CTE and this is my attempt
**WITH ManagerInfo(Empid, empName)
AS
(
  Select DISTINCT Empid, empName 
  From Emp where EmpId IN(Select ManagerId from emp)
)

Select e.EmpName, MI.EmpName
FROM Emp e INNER JOIN ManagerInfo MI**

Comment: how can I make it recursive ?

Comment: When I am running above query I am getting below error *Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "MgrName" of recursive query "Hierarchy".*

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite: see my answer - you need to have **two `SELECT`** statement - the first defining the "anchor", the second defining the recursion - that are combined with a `UNION ALL`

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite: sorry, yes - I had `VARCHAR(50)` instead of `NVARCHAR(50)` in my cast. You also have a funny `COLLATE .... ` specifier in our table definition; I would **remove that** if ever possible! Otherwise it might cause even more issues......

Comment: I have written this query 
**;WITH ManagerInfo(Empid, empName)
AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT Empid, empName 
  FROM Emp where EmpId IN(SELECT ManagerId FROM emp)
)

SELECT e.EmpName, 'No Manager' as empName
FROM Emp e
WHERE e.ManagerId IS NULL OR e.ManagerId = 0
UNION
SELECT e.EmpName, MI.empName
FROM Emp e RIGHT OUTER Join ManagerInfo MI ON E.ManagerId = MI.Empid**

Comment: Can you please guide me if anything wrong you find in my query?

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite: there's nothing **wrong** with your query - it's just **NOT** a recursive CTE..... as I said: look at my answer - **THAT** is a recursive CTE, and only that will work to give you want you're looking for.... SEE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are correct: you don't have to use a temporary table just for this. Try using recursive queries. [Take a look at this link on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx). There is an example with ManagerId/EmployeeID. Just as in your query.