# select all parent of child in the same table

Tags: sql-server-2008

i need to display all parent of one child on the same table
where i have table as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GOV_SIDE_Tbl](
[Gov_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Gov_Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Gov_Parent_ID] [int] NULL

 CONSTRAINT [PK_GOV_SIDE_Tbl] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Gov_ID] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,           ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY] 
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

how i can get full gov side name using parent ID

```
ie.
Gov_ID     Gov_Name          Gov_Parent_ID
1       Ministry of Finance      0
2         Finance Dept1          1
```

so when i pass Gov_ID=2

```
the returned full name will be:
"Finance Dept1-Ministry of Finance"
```

Comment: It's also answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111771/select-parent-and-child-from-the-same-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a recursive function with a base condition (ParentID=0) witch take the child ID and in turn get the name of current ID concatenated with the recursive call result.

```
CREATE function dbo.GetPath (@id int)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name nvarchar(max);
    DECLARE @parenID int;
    select @name=Name,@parenID=ParentID from [Table] where ID=@id;
    if(@parenID=0)
        RETURN @name;
    RETURN @name +' / '+ dbo.GetPath(@parenID);
END
```

This solution is constrained by 32 level nested calls.

Comment: i need to be my friend Please